# Find overlapping area of each class in classified images

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator, classification, statistics

I have three classified satellite images, lets say 2005, 2010, and 2015. 
All images are similar i.e. the same total area and same number of classes.

I want to output those areas where pixels of all three classification matches/overlap.

For example: Find pixels that is classified in "class A" in all three images.

Is there any way to do it in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Spatial Analyst, you can use [combine tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combine.htm) which will combine all the attributes of the 3 raster data together in one attribute table. Then use field calculator to select those raster values that satisfy the condition you want.

If you don't have Spatial Analyst, then convert the raster data into polygon and use [Intersect tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm).

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful response. :)